# Parton Distribution Functions plot

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

I was looking at a plot of the parton distribution functions today and had a question. On the y axis, it seems like the value of x f(x) for gluons is greater than one at small x. I was under the impression that parton distribution functions are probability densities and cannot be greater than one. Also, x is a fraction of momentum and can also not be greater than one. Does anyone know why this is?

[link to PDF image](http://www.google.com/imgres?um=1&hl=en&sa=N&biw=1920&bih=821&tbm=isch&tbnid=T1lUDiMsjtq3oM%3a&imgrefurl=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCTEQ6_parton_distribution_functions.png&docid=6IDx1_-MUSW2_M&imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0d/CTEQ6_parton_distribution_functions.png&w=1024&h=717&ei=pTYtUMTxMOXj0QHI9YHYDQ&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=158&vpy=138&dur=87&hovh=188&hovw=268&tx=129&ty=104&sig=101432623456645059726&page=1&tbnh=106&tbnw=144&start=0&ndsp=58&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:76)

Thanks!

Comment: *"Also, x is a fraction of momentum and can also not be greater than one. Does anyone know why this is?"* [Bjorken x](http://unh-npg.wikidot.com/bjorken-x) *can* be greater than one, thought this is rare. It implies the rest of the mass of the compound object moving momentarily backwards in the lab frame.

Comment: *I was under the impression that parton distribution functions are probability densities and cannot be greater than one.* here is the wrong statement.

Comment: More about x>1. See the two [experiment from JLAB's Hall C](http://www.jlab.org/exp_prog/generated/apphallc.html) with "x>1" in their titles. I also understand that there is another instance planned once the 12 GeV upgrade is complete.

Answer (score 2):

A probability cannot be greater than 1, but a probability *density* can be. The parton distribution represents basically the probability per unit momentum fraction, so it can be large over a small region of $x$ without contributing much to the actual probability, $\int f(x)\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Nor is the integral required to be one, as there are multiple up valence quarks in a proton and an indefinite number of sea quarks and gluons.

Comment: Actually, I think the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ can be interpreted as the average value of the particle number operator, and that average is going to be 1 by definition. (I had to think about it for a while to reconvince myself of this)